# Ctrl+left mouse button multiple copy lines of code like Word in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I need to be able to select/copy multiple lines of code with Notepad++ just like word/openoffice writer does when you select text by Ctrl+left mouse button.

Lets say I find line 10 i want to select from my code and further down i want to paste line 20 and line 40. If I was in Word i would just do Ctrl+left to the lines and I would paste em somewhere else.

Is this possible in Notepad++ ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option on Notepad++: Options->Preferences->Editing->Multi-Editing Settings. This will turn on the feature you want to use.